# how to strip characters right of '_' in node name using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

my requirement is to rename all the node names which has _ in them to new name. 
how to strip the char right of _ present in a node name and leave the left side of the name as the new node name? e.g

```
<abc_2013></abc_2013> to be renamed as <abc></abc>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '_')]">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name(),'_')}"
               namespace="{namespace-uri()}">

     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<abc_2013>xYz</abc_2013>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<abc>xYz</abc>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Proper use of the function **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)**